# Laravel send json response from inner function

Tags: php, laravel

So Im building an API. 
But I keep running into returning a json response from an inner function.

If I do the following then laravel sends a backlog or error log to the client. That should never ever happen in a api. So how do you do this in Laravel?

I want to return json immediately and stop excecuting without showing the client any other information

```
public function functionThatIsCalledByClient($data)
{
     $this->validateSomething($data);
}

private function validateSomething($data)
{
    if(! $data ) ) return response()->json(['error' => 'some message'], 400)->send();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So... store result of `validateSomething` into a variable, check its contents and if it's not a boolean, return it?

Comment: And end up with duplicated code if you do this 10 times because send() adds all kinds of stuff I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `abort` helper for that or, for complex cases, [error handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors).

In case of abort:

```
private function validateSomething($data)
{
    if(! $data )  // you can create a custom helper function to wrap this code.
       abort(400, json_encode(['error'=>'some error']), ['Content-Type: application/json']);

    return true;
}
```

---

In case of general handler:

```
private function validateSomething($data)
{
    if(! $data ) 
       throw new \Exception('some message');

    return true;
}
```

Inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` @ render

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof Exception)
        return response()
                ->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
                //->send(); should not be necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've made me find the anwser! 

In my case abort didn't work, used that before because the error handler would render a view, I've changed things to the exceptions/handler.php

I chose to make a custom exception that returns jason and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

throw new GeneralException('invalid required extra quantity');